# Obtaining line of code metrics from Visual Studio Team Services for specific dates and project?

Tags: version-control, metrics, azure-devops, changeset

We currently use Visual Studio Team Services for our source control. Unfortunately, we do not use the project planning capabilities with VS team services. Meaning when we check-in code we do not map the source code to work items in a sprint.

Is it possible to query line of code changes for specific dates and certain application/solution from VS Team Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Git and TFVC have this information available, by linking your [Visual Studio Team Services account to Power BI](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/report/report-on-vso-with-power-bi-vs). The Git Activity and TFVC Activity reports provide a starting point, though for now the period you can report on is limited.

Comment: First time hearing about Power BI, does it only require a MSDN subscription? Is it just a web tool to pull data from VSO to create reports and dashboards?

Comment: It's an online reporting and dashboard solution. I'm not versed in the license requirements. Any other solution will require you to process the data manually using the TFS apis.

Comment: It's worth noting that analytics for Power BI is in private preview currently and inaccessible unless you're in the preview